# Query github api by location and language

Tags: github, github-api

How can I query the github api by a location AND a programming language, and is there any pagination feature in the api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible to search repositories using location, via either site search or the API search, since **`location` is an attribute on a user, not a repository**.

As for pagination, the API claims to have it, but the [online docs](http://develop.github.com/p/repo.html) say to use `?start_page=N` while [Github support is saying](http://support.github.com/discussions/api/287-is-it-possible-to-access-page-2-3-etc-of-the-results-of-a-search-query-via-the-api) to use `?page=N`.  I've tested and neither of these worked for me: I always get the first page, and no combination of parameters seem to advance to the next batch of results.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, pagination works something like this (below code works):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var url = 'https://api.github.com/users/andrew/repos?page=1&per_page=100';

    $.getJSON(url + '&callback=?',null,function(data)
    {
        var output = JSON.stringify(data);

        document.write(output);
    });
});
```